# How to build list of structs

Tags: go

I’ve multiple yaml files which need to be parsed and have exactly the same structure

```
schema: "1.0.0"
id: test
version: "1.2.3"


dependency :
 - name: ui
    type: runner
    cwd: /ui
    install:
       - name: api
         group: test
         properties:
             name: app
             url: appUrl

 - name: backend
    type: mongoDb
    path: be
    install:
       - name: db
         type: mongo
    provides:
       - name: api
         properties:
            url: url
```

- The `schema` section is `mandatory` for all the yaml which the app should
  get always
- The `dependency` tag can contain `1..n` entries with mandatory fields such as
  `,name, type, cwd`
- The `dependency` tag can (or not) contain `instal`l section with `name` and
  `properties` which is `mandatory`
- The dependency tag can (or not) contain `provides` section with `name`
  which is mandatory

The `install` can have `properties` and the `provides` also can have `properties`

I am using a yaml parser to parse the files but my question is how in Golang I can build struct that when I parse the doc it will automatically fill the main struct and will include the sub structs (such as dependency/ install sections )

The code which done the parse and working is the following:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

var data = `
schema: "1.0.0"
id: test
version: "1.2.3"


dependency :
  - name: ui
    type: runner
    cwd: /ui
    install:
       - name: api
         group: test
         properties:
             name: app
             url: appUrl

  - name: backend
    type: mongoDb
    cwd: be
    install:
       - name: db
         type: mongo
    provides:
       - name: api
         properties:
             url: url
`

type Yaml struct {
    Schema     string
    ID         string
    Version    string
    Dependency []Dependency
}

type Dependency struct {
    Name     string
    Type     string
    CWD      string
    Install  []Install
    Provides []Provide
}

type Install struct {
    Name       string
    Group      string
    Type       string
    Properties Properties
}

type Properties struct {
    Name string
    URL  string
}

type Provide struct {
    Name       string
    Properties Properties
}

func main() {
    y := Yaml{}

    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &y)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", y)

}
```

My question are:

1. The install section can have `group` and `properties` so how should I contract the struct to handle this options nicely
2. if the `main` is under `rootProj-> cmd>main.go` assume that the struct's should be extended , how should I build the project structure?

if my project is like following:

```
myproj
  vendor
  cmd
    main.go
  Gopkg.lock
  Gopkg.toml
```

Should I create another folder under the root and put the struct there ?